# Trying to display a MySQL table as cshtml

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to display a MySQL table but its telling me it needs a data source so I I've tried `grid.DataSource = UserList;` and etc. nothing seems to be working.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(Models.SearchModel user)
{

    List<Models.SearchModel> UserList = new List<Models.SearchModel>();

    MySqlConnection connection = DBConnect.getconnection(); // setting connection to database
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetUsers", connection); // search for procedure called "GetData"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?search", MySqlDbType.VarChar)); // search parameters, if not looking for anythinf gets all the data
    cmd.Parameters["?search"].Value = "%" + "" + "%";
    cmd.Parameters["?search"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // telling program to read Data
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt16(dr["ID"]);
        string user_name = Convert.ToString(dr["user_name"]); // converting data to a string

        Models.SearchModel UserMod = new Models.SearchModel(id, user_name);

        UserList.Add(UserMod);

    }

    dr.Close(); // close

    DBConnect.CloseConnection(connection); // closes connection

    return View("Search", UserList);
}
```

on the cshtml page I have the following code:

```
@model IEnumerable<AOSExpress.Models.SearchModel>
<div>
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(@Model);        
}
@grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `WebGrid` but, from your view above, you're not passing `Model` correctly to it.  Your view should be:

```
@model IEnumerable<AOSExpress.Models.SearchModel>
<div>
@{
    // Notice the removal of the @ symbol
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model);        
}
@grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

`@{ ... }` in Razor denotes a code block and `@` simply outputs whatever it's prefixing.  In this case, as you're trying to pass `Model` as a parameter to the `WebGrid` constructor, rather than outputting the contents of `Model`, you don't need to prefix it with the `@` symbol.